# How to change Navigation Drawer icon size?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, navigation-drawer

It is possible to change `Navigation Drawer` icon size? I need to make it bigger because I made the toolbar bigger and now the button is too small.

[image]

I tried to add this line in `dimens.xml` but didn't work

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">10dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Hide navigation icon in toolbar and create your own toolbar.

Comment: You need change icon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479575/changing-navigation-drawer-hamburger-icon